# Find and replace it with new value in sql query in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to list all the states. For examples values in  my state table is

```
01 - Tamilnadu
2 - Andhra
03 - MP
4 - Kerala
```

etc.,,

What i need is if the number before - is one digit then i have to append zero with it. For example andhra have only one digit i need it as 02 - Andhra during the selection else return the value as it is. Here is my try, it has lot of syntax error. Can you please any one help me to complete my query please.

```
select [state],case(len(SUBSTRING([state],1,CHARINDEX('-', [state]+'-')-1)))
when  1 then
state = append zero in the state
when 2
state = leave value as it is
End
 from states where [state] is not null order by id desc;
```

Thanks

Comment: If I was you I'd move the number to a new INT column

Comment: When you say to replace do you mean to update the values in the table, or you need just a select statement?

Comment: These are not two different column. its one column, i need to add zero at the begining only if my state have only one number before the character -. or else it should select as it is. for example, during the selection now andhra have only one number before -. i need 02 - Andhra like that. for Tamilnadu it should not add any zero because it has already two digits

Comment: only select statement is enough

Comment: @user1845163 OK. See an answer for possible solutions for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution if you need to fix digits while you do a `SELECT`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state LIKE '[0-9] - %'
            THEN '0' + state
            ELSE state
       END state
  FROM states
 WHERE state IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Sample output:

```
state
--------------
01 - Tamilnadu
02 - Andhra
03 - MP
04 - Kerala
```

If you need to update such values

```
UPDATE states
  SET state = '0' + state
 WHERE state LIKE '[0-9] - %'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select right('0'+state,2), statename
from states
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Right('00'+cast(ColumnName As varchar),2)
from TableName

Select Right('00'+cast(state As varchar),2), StateName
from States where [state] is not null order by id desc;
```

Comment: Hi I have modified your query to match my requirement, but its adding 0 to all the state which numeric length have more than one. this is my modified one.   Select left('0'+cast(state As varchar),len(state)), StateName
from States where [state] is not null order by id desc; Can you please help me to add the zero only if - before has only one numeric values

Comment: try edited code.., also you want to change right() instead left()

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to concatenate and then take the right hand most characters.

Like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[state]), 2) + ' - ' + Name
FROM states
WHERE [state] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

If for some reason the `[state]` column contains all of the data (e.g. `'1 - Tamilnadu'`), then you need to modify it to be like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + [state], LEN([state]))
FROM states
WHERE [state] IS NOT NULL
```

Although it would be better to separate out the id.

Comment: modified your query like below to match my requirement. SELECT left('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[state]), 1)  + [state] FROM states. during the selection its displaying 001 - Tamilnadu it should not alter the value before - if it has two characters. it should alter only 2- Andhra, because here before - only one numeric character

Answer (score 0):

```
Select replicate('0',2-len(stateId)) + cast(stateid as varchar) +'-' + state_name as  StateName
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this.

```
SELECT state, 
CASE LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(state, '-', 1)) 
WHEN 1 
THEN CONCAT('0', state) 
END AS changedstate
FROM  states 
WHERE state ID NOT NULL 
ORDER BY id desc;
```

Thank you